# Elegant way to convert active record data into JS chart structure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I think convert database data to  chart structure,

It's a really painful job with ruby.

Take a example,

I want to show a line chart.

## X-axi (Time: Month), Y-axi (Value)

I need to `union` the Months among datasets

Then extract values from each datasets,

If there is `no data` for the corresponding month

You need to padding zero or any other value, you can not leave it null. otherwise the chart will be shifted.

I wonder if there is any elegant way to solve my problem.

Because to generate a chart. it's suck a hard and verbosed job for me. Thanks

## datasets 1 (get from active record)

```
Month: January, value: 65
Month: February, value: 59
Month: April, value: 81
```

## datasets 2 (get from active record)

```
Month: January, value: 28
Month: March, value: 40
```

## data structure for js chart

```
    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April"],
    datasets: [
        {
            data: [65, 59, 0, 81]
        },
        {
            data: [28, 0, 40, 0]
        }
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Think in terms of hashes and arrays, and get yourself acquainted with methods such as `Array#map`.

```
irb(main):002:0> d1 = [["January", 65], ["February", 59], ["April", 81]];
irb(main):003:0* d2 = [["January", 28], ["March", 40]];

irb(main):007:0> h1 = Hash[d1]
=> {"January"=>65, "February"=>59, "April"=>81}
irb(main):008:0> h2 = Hash[d2]
=> {"January"=>28, "March"=>40}

irb(main):009:0> months = ["January", "February", "March", "April"]
=> ["January", "February", "March", "April"]

irb(main):010:0> months.map{ |month| h1[month] }
=> [65, 59, nil, 81]
irb(main):011:0> months.map{ |month| h1[month] || 0 }
=> [65, 59, 0, 81]

irb(main):012:0> [h1,h2].map{ |dataset| months.map{ |month| dataset[month] || 0 } }
=> [[65, 59, 0, 81], [28, 0, 40, 0]]
irb(main):015:0> [h1,h2].map{ |ds| {data: months.map{ |month| ds[month] || 0 }} }
=> [{:data=>[65, 59, 0, 81]}, {:data=>[28, 0, 40, 0]}]

irb(main):017:0> dsets = [h1,h2].map{ |ds| {data: months.map{ |month| ds[month] || 0 }} }
=> [{:data=>[65, 59, 0, 81]}, {:data=>[28, 0, 40, 0]}]
irb(main):018:0> {labels: months, dataset: dsets}
=> {:labels=>["January", "February", "March", "April"], :dataset=>[{:data=>[65, 59, 0, 81]}, {:data=>[28, 0, 40, 0]}]}
```

Comment: `months.map` saves me from lots of `if else confitions`